# Not able to take input in Visual Studio code (macOS version), solution highly appreciated

Tags: c++, visual-studio, input

[image: screenshot]

I'm giving input in VS Code on macOS (Catalina version). But it is not taking input, I tried many things. And of course I'm not able to enter inout in the terminal. I have attached a snapshot of what the terminal shows.

Comment: Please post all code _as text_ into the question. I'm really curious why people find it easier to make a screenshot and upload it somewhere, than to copy and paste 10 lines of code.

Comment: To address your actual problem, even it may be a stupid question, but what did you expect to happen? That file is unsaved (maybe doesn't even exist on disk?). Do you know, that C++ needs to be compiled into a program first? It's not interpreted like python.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running a python script on your VScode terminal for a C++ program?

*`g++ -o nameofprogram nameofprogram.cpp`*

and run your program as

*`./nameofprogram`* and you will see a blank line to enter input.